# CSS Animation doesn't re-occur after second jQuery call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a CSS animation effect that makes text blink 3 times. I want it to reset its state every time I get different response (in example below, buttons are acting as response)

How could I achieve resetting the state of CSS animation through jQuery?

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.replaceClass = function(pFromClass, pToClass) {
    return this.removeClass(pFromClass).addClass(pToClass);
  };
}(jQuery));

$("#true").click(function() {
  $('#animate').replaceClass('false flashit', 'true flashit');
  console.log("True clicked");
});

$("#false").click(function() {
  $('#animate').replaceClass('true flashit', 'false flashit');
  console.log("False clicked");
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
  0%,
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes flash {
  0%,
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.flashit {
  -webkit-animation: flash linear 1s 3;
  -moz-animation: flash linear 1s 3;
  animation: flash linear 1s 3
}

.true {
  color: green
}

.false {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="animate">I am going to get animated!</span>
<div>
  <p style="margin-bottom:5px">These buttons are acting as response</p>
  <button id="true">True</button>
  <button id="false">False</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to clear the animation name (or get rid of flashit class) on an animationend event - otherwise the system thinks it's done the animation and won't run it again.

Comment: I tried to use ```myspanSelector.style.animationName = "none"; requestAnimationFrame(() => { setTimeout(() => { myspanSelector.style.animationName = ""}, 0); });``` but didn't work

Comment: How are you listening for the animationend event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that immediately adding the class `flashit` back to the element after removing it doesnt register that the class was added again.

When adding a `setTimeout` within your replace function after removing the class, it works. Notice that there is no delay specified for the timeout, so we basically just wait for the `removeClass` part to finish and then immediately schedule the the execution of `addClass`.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.replaceClass = function(pFromClass, pToClass) {
    this.removeClass(pFromClass)
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.addClass(pToClass);
    });
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

$("#true").click(function() {
  $('#animate').replaceClass('false flashit', 'true flashit');
  console.log("True clicked");
});

$("#false").click(function() {
  $('#animate').replaceClass('true flashit', 'false flashit');
  console.log("False clicked");
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
  0%,
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes flash {
  0%,
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.flashit {
  -webkit-animation: flash linear 1s 3;
  -moz-animation: flash linear 1s 3;
  animation: flash linear 1s 3
}

.true {
  color: green
}

.false {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="animate">I am going to get animated!</span>
<div>
  <p style="margin-bottom:5px">These buttons are acting as response</p>
  <button id="true">True</button>
  <button id="false">False</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice catch, I tried to use `setTimeout()` before posting question but in a very different way :), thank you!